# python script error : Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, debugging, testing, exception

we wrote a python test script to automate a few tasks including adding service accounts and resource groups .  At execution I get an error message :

**'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sa_clientId' referenced before assignment'**

i read a few stackoverflow threads where they speak about problems related to global variables. But sa_clientId is not a global variable. So i don't understand what i am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.
please find below the function that triggers the crash at execution.

```
def create_service_account(bearer_token, parent_rg_id, rg_id, rg_name, roles):
    
    global sa_db
    
    print('>> Creating service account for rg %s with rg_id %s' % (rg_name, rg_id))
    print(type(roles), len(roles))
    print(roles)
    print(parent_rg_id)

    url = "https://<snipped>/api/controlplane/" + parent_rg_id + "/serviceaccounts"

    payload = json.dumps({
      "name": "Client %s - %s" % (rg_name, str(roles)),
      "resourceGroups": [
        {
          "resourceGroupId": rg_id,
          "roles": roles
        }
      ]
    })
    headers = {
      'api-version': '1.1',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer_token
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(response.text)
    
    if response.text != '':
        sa_infos = json.loads(response.text)
        sa_clientSecret = sa_infos['secret']['value']
        sa_clientId = sa_infos['clientId']
        sa_id = sa_infos['id']
        sa_name = sa_infos['name']
        sa_rg = sa_infos['resourceGroups']

        sa_db[sa_clientId] = {
          'secret': sa_clientSecret,
          'id': sa_id,
          'name': sa_name,
          'resourceGroups': sa_rg
        }


    return sa_clientId
```

Comment: You don't define `sa_clientId` at all if `response.text != ''` condition is not met, so it fails when you try to return it. It would also be easier to debug if you provided full stack trace.

Comment: Please post minimal code that we can detect the problem much easier.

Answer (score 0):

well in the above code you only assign "clientId" when it passes through
"if response.text != '':", by doing so and returning "clientId" it would be referenced before assignment unless it passes through the if statement.
try adding a default value state.

Ex.

```
def take_command():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        try:
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            if 'hey jarvis' in command:
                command = command.replace('hey jarvis', '')
                print(command)
        except:
            command = ''
    return command
```

if it doesn't recieve any audio then it passes through the exception but is still assigned a value of ''. without it, it would also return 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sa_clientId' referenced before assignment'